# How to store word compositions in a relational database in a normalized way?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, orm, relational, relational-database

I'm trying to find a nice way to store word compositions of the following form:

```
exhaustcleaningsystem
exhaust cleaning system
exhaustcleaning system
exhaust cleaningsystem
```

The combinations are given by a default per case. Every word in a composition is stored as a unique row in table 'labels'.

```
labels
id   value
--------------------------
1    exhaustcleaningsystem
2    exhaust
3    cleaning
4    system
5    exhaustcleaning
6    cleaningsystem
```

I thought about a new table called 'compositions':

```
compositions
id   domain_id   range
----------------------
1    1           2,3,4
2    1           5,4
etc...
```

But storing multiple separated values in a column isn't normalized design. Any ideas for that?

BTW: I'm using MySQL und ActiveRecord/Rails.

Comment: I think we could help better with more background : 
why do you want to store all those combinations and what are you doing with them ?

And, yes, separated values in a column smells bad ... you will have hard times using them with many tools and will have lots of code to write to cope with them (even if you use them just in one place today)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The design you propose is not even in first normal form, since range is not atomic

The schema I'd use here would be

```
compositions
id   domain_id
-------------
1    1
2    1

compositions-content
composition_id        rank        label_id
------------------------------------------
1                     1           2
1                     2           3
1                     3           4
2                     1           5
2                     2           4
```

with composition_id referencing an composition.id and label_id referencing label.id

The rank column is optional and should be here if and only if the range you define here is order-sensitive.

With this design, you have some referential integrity at DB level.

Answer (score 0):

Well, this is as far as I can think of in terms of normalisation:

```
sets
id   domain_id
--------------
1    1
2    1
etc...
```

```
compositions
id  set_id  label_id  order
---------------------------
1   1       2         1
2   1       3         2
3   1       4         3
4   2       5         1
5   2       4         2
etc...
```